# Matrix Pointer C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix

This code supposedly creates a 2-d array dynamically. But can't understand head or tail of it. If only someone could explain what this code does step by step, it would be a great help. Help appreciated!

```
#include<iostream.h>

class matrix{
     int **p;
     int d1, d2;

 public:
     matrix(int x, int y);
     void get_element(int i, int j, int value){ p[i][j]=value; }
     int &put_element(int i,int j) { return p[i][j]; }
};

matrix::matrix(int x, int y){      
    d1 = x;
    d2 = y;
    p = new int *[d1];
    for(int i = 0; i < d1; i++) p[i] = new int[d2];
}

int main(){
    int m, n;
    cout << "enter size of matrix:";
    cin >> m >> n;
    matrix A(m, n);

    cout << "enter matrix elements row by row\n";
    int i, j, value;

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cin >> value;
            A.get_element(i, j, value);
        }
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "A.put_element(1, 2);

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: the first step of understanding a code is to make it more "human-readable": indent it, add comments on the known and unknown segments, etc.

Comment: @Ziezi thanks for the tip! Will implement it hereafter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key to understanding this is the constructor:

```
matrix::matrix(int x,int y)
 {      
  d1=x;
  d2=y;
  p=new int *[d1];
  for(int i=0;i<d1;i++)
  p[i]=new int[d2];
 }
```

What is fashioned first is a "container" of rows, where each row is to be an array of integers. An array of integers is stored as a pointer, when dynamically allocated. As such `new int *[d1]` creates a new array of pointers to integers for d1 entries. Each entry in that array is a pointer, not initialized at first. Now, an array of pointers can be stored via a "pointer to a pointer", which in this class is declared as `int **p;` This can be read as a pointer to the base of an array of pointers, since that's what is intended in this case. The "double pointer" idiom has other uses, sometimes (bad ones, really, from the C style language usage), but in this case it's there to store an array of pointers to integers.

Now, for each row,`p[i]=new int[d2]` creates an array of integers. The array is stored via a pointer to an integer, identified as `p[i]`.

Therefore, the row `p[0]` is of type `int *`. If I declared:

```
int * row = p[1];
```

Then row would be an array of integers from row 1 of the matrix.

This means that `p[1][1]` gets cell 1,1 of the matrix, or the column 1 from row 1. In your example, the functions get_element and put_element appear to be reversed in name. The get_element function actually places a value in the matrix. The statement `p[i][j]=value` found in get_element is, instead of getting a value, writing a value to the cell at i,j.

Curiously, the function put_element could actually serve both purposes, because it returns a reference to the integer at the cell i,j. It's name lies about it's purpose. Let's say, for clarity, we called it at, as in:

```
int & at(int i, int j )
{
 return p[i][j];
}
```

Now, this works both ways (which may be the wrong design choice, but...)

```
int x = m.at( i, j ); // getting a value;
m.at( i, j ) = 4;     // writing a value;
```

This is because it is returning a reference. You could even use it like:

```
int & rv = m.at( i, j );
```

Now, whatever you do to rv you're also doing to the cell at i,j.

This was probably a mistake. The names should be reversed, but a GET function should not return a reference, usually, unless it's a const &. You usually don't want "getters" to allow changes to be made.

The sample program is a little dangerous. The input isn't checked for sanity, so this could easily try to allocated GBytes of ram. That aside, it should be obvious that taking in values and applying them to a matrix with a function named "get_element" seems odd. It's setting, or putting, or writing, but not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind to create a 2D array you must have a pointer to a pointer at some point, this is the **p. If you wanted to do a 3D array, you would need ***p somewhere. d1 and d2 are the dimensions or how large the array is.

The matrix::matrix(int x,int y) { ... part deal with creating the array. The dimension var di and d2 are updated.

The p=new int *[d1]; ... allocates an array of pointers of length d1, so now p is a pointer, pointing to an array of pointers. This has just created the 1D of the array. Think of this in terms of rows going down, as the first index in this array would be the top row of the 2D array.

The for loop essentially creates an array of length d2 for each pointer in the pointer array. The 2D is now created data can be edited and accessed by p[row][column] or this may be easier p[y][x].

Side note I think the put_element and
 get_element are backwards, they both seem to do what the other should.